# decimal place value not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, decimalformat

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here. I have a double:

`let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609.344` and the results are `2.99685063032388e-09`

But I want to round the number to one decimal place, so I do this:

```
let miles = String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMiles)
```

But when I print it out miles = 0.0. The decimal place works but it turns my number into 0 instead of 2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2.99685063032388e-09` is not equal to `2.9`, it is `0.00000000299685063032388`

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.99685063032388e-09

There is actually a cool way to do this, using the exponent format specifier instead of float. (From this list https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

```
let miles = String(format: "%.1e", distanceInMiles)
```

Comment: oh my goodness, you are completely right!! I totally ignored the exponents

Comment: @juelizabeth added another snippet in case you actually wanted to print two decimals + exponent.

Comment: Thank you very much! it helped a lot